# How to send text data get from previous activity to API

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am new to react-native. I want to send my data which is text to API. How to do it?

from this coding I can get the data from FirstActivity but how to send that data to API in second activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you receiving the data in `this.props.navigation.state.params.no`?

If so, you can send it in [componentDidMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) which should trigger when you navigate to the second page or you can use some [react-navigation lifecycles](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-lifecycle.html). For example, I will use componentDidMount

```
 class SecondActivity extends Component{
         static navigationOptions =
            {
                title: "Second Activity"
            };
    componentDidMount(){  //this will trigger everytime the screen is mounted
       this.callAPI() /we call a function that handles the API call 
    }
    async callAPI(){ //is async because i like it 7u7
      var numberReceived = this.props.navigation.state.params.no
       var Result = await fetch ....... //call API here and use the number received variable in it
    }
    render() {
            return (
            <View style= {styles.MainContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.textStyle}>
                1 = {this.props.navigation.state.params.no}
                </Text>
            </View>
            )}
    }
```

The implementation really depends on the API you are trying to use. they should have some docs explaining what you should do to call the API. Of course, you should have some basic knowledge of the [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) API or the xmlhttprequest API